# Почему при закрытие браузера происходит ошибки "'IE.window' - есть null или не является объектом", "объект не поддерживает это свойство или метод"?

Tags: javascript, bat, internet-explorer

У меня есть следующий объект браузера

```
var IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application");
```

и при вызове типа

```
IE.open('','_self').close();
```

я получаю ошибку

> Ошибка выполнения Microsoft JScript: Объект не поддерживает это свойство или метод

а при `IE.window.open('','_self').close();`

> Ошибка выполнения Microsoft JScript: 'IE.window' -  есть null или не является объектом

Как закрыть браузер по завершению моего скрипта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "ie_");
IE.visible = true;
IE.Navigate("about:blank");

//ждем окончания загрузки
while (IE.ReadyState != 4) {
  WScript.Sleep(100);
}

WScript.Echo(IE.Document); //можно работать с DOM
//список всех свойств объекта IE: 
//https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752084(v%3Dvs.85)
//не знаю как получить доступ к window, может кто знает

//закрываем браузер
IE.Quit();
```

Comment: интересно что лучше использовать `while (IE.Busy)` или `while (IE.ReadyState != 4)`